# Getting a specific child to the Firebase RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Building Users Activity , trying to retrieve specific info from database(name,sold items and date) getting this from All users class and my Database reference and show it in a Recyclerview on my app.

My Database

[image]

Tried FirebaseUI-Android for that https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/

MY APP CRASH !

My code:

```
  @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startListening();
    }

    public void startListening(){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Users")
                .limitToLast(50);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ALL_USERS> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ALL_USERS>()
                        .setQuery(query, ALL_USERS.class)
                        .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ALL_USERS, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.users_card_layout, parent, false);

                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, int i, @NonNull ALL_USERS all_users) {
                usersViewHolder.setName(all_users.getName());
            }
        };

        mUsersList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();


    }


    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;


        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView=itemView;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            TextView userNameView = mView.findViewById(R.id.Users_Name);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }
    }


}
```

ALL Users class :

```
public class ALL_USERS {

    public String name;
    public String SonyTV;
    public String Date;

    public ALL_USERS() {
    }

    public ALL_USERS(String name, String sonyTV, String date) {
        this.name = name;
        SonyTV = sonyTV;
        Date = date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSonyTV() {
        return SonyTV;
    }

    public void setSonyTV(String sonyTV) {
        SonyTV = sonyTV;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

My Logcat:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: date
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:545)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:476)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:317)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:2418)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:212)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:35)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:106)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at an
```

my second Logcat

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:2413)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:178)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:591)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:2550)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:212)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:35)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:106)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at 

    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5620)
```

Comment: Please add the content of your `ALL_USERS` class.

Comment: Added @AlexMamo

Comment: Added with second logcat the actual error when i go to users activity (this activity) the app crash!!

Comment: I changed letters in my code and deleted the old ones in my database as you mentioned with the small letters like the ALL USERS class

Comment: The fact that you get another error, it means that the initial error disappeared and this are **good** news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question. We usually stick to one question at a time but because I think you're really close, I ask you again to show me the two remaining things. The new database structure and the code you are using, ok?

Comment: There's no longer necessary, I've found your second problem. Please see my updated answer. The **`date`** property should be of type `long` and not String. Does it work now?

Comment: Dear Alex i have one more thing i cant get the child sonyTV in the RecyclerView ,is it beacause its not a direct child of Users node ??!!!

Comment: Yes, that's right. You should add an extra `child("User Sold Items")` call, before getting the value.

Comment: Can you help me in this?? or i should ask a new question for that ??? :)

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the the last comment and ask another question if something else comes up ;)

Comment: I tried to retrieve with the ValueEventListener but its crashed , i think theres another way to call it, Anyway im posting a new question for that ,thank you Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you have in your `ALL_USERS` class a field named `Date` but you are using a getter named `getDate()`, which is not correct since Firebase is looking in the database for a field named **`date`** and not `Date`. See the lowercase `d` letter vs. capital letter `D`?

There are two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to change your model class by renaming the fields according to the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). So you model class should look like this:

```
public class ALL_USERS {
    private String name, sonyTV;
    private long date;

    public ALL_USERS() {}

    public ALL_USERS(String name, String sonyTV, long date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sonyTV = sonyTV;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getSonyTV() { return sonyTV; }
    public long getDate() { return date; }
}
```

See in this example, there are `private` fields and public getters. There is also a simpler solution, to set the value directly on public fields like this:

```
public class ALL_USERS {
    public String name, sonyTV;
    public long date;
}
```

Now just remove the current data and add it again using the correct names. This solution will work only if you are in testing phase.

There is also the second approach, which is to use `annotations`. So if you prefer to use private fields and public getters, you should use the [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation only in front of the getter. So your `ALL_USERS` class should look like this:

```
public class ALL_USERS {
    private String name, SonyTV;
    private long Date;

    public ALL_USERS() {}

    public ALL_USERS(String name, String sonyTV, long date) {
        this.name = name;
        SonyTV = sonyTV;
        Date = date;
    }

    public String getName() { return mame; }
    @PropertyName("SonyTV")
    public String getSonyTV() { return SonyTV; }
    @PropertyName("Date")
    public long getDate() { return Date; }
}
```

Comment: Ahaaaa, i understand may be thats why it was crashing.But, its still not showing date and SonyTV child(s) !!!!

Comment: For sure, this why I answered your question. Have you tried my solution, does it work?

Comment: yes i did change my class but when im trying to get date in my main activity with                 usersViewHolder.setDate(all_users.getDate());
 public void setDate(String date) {

            TextView userDateView = mView.findViewById(R.id.LastTime);
            userDateView.setText(date);
        }

Comment: In that case, you should remove the actual data from your database and add fresh data. So your fields can exist with the new names (`name, sonyTV and date`), not as it is now, uisng capital letters. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it here.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know whats stack trace but i can edit my question with the second Logcat , please check it

Comment: Yes, please **add** 3 things. The actual error, the new database and the code that you are using now.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The second error should also disappear. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Thank you so much for what you did now its working ,Thanks for your patience with me :D